# Is the Marx Bank Still the Gold Standard?

Tags: magnetic-fields, plasma-physics, fusion

Is the Marx bank still the fastest pulse forming network for generating high magnetic fields at large scale, or is there another design that outperforms it?

Comment: Just a Marx bank with no other circuit elements? No, as can be seen by the layout of, for example, the Z Machine.

Comment: Note that "gold standard," "bank," and "Marx" have common meanings in finance and political philosophy, which makes the title of this question something of a [garden-path sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden-path_sentence). You might attract better attention to this question about physics/engineering by editing the title.